# PHP generate fixed string

Tags: php

I have a website that needs to generate a fixed prefixed strings and the order id as the invoice number.

The current code is 
    $cnt    = strlen($order->id);
    $remain = 20-$cnt;
    $data['invoiceNo']  = $this->generateRandomString($remain).$order->id;

How to i change it to have a prefix of `JGJEPOSONLINECS + order id` instead of `random string + order id`

Comment: Please give more information

Comment: its a woocommerce integration with a bank UAT server. We used an external plugin to generate the invoice, but the code we have to integrate with the bank generates random string , instead of the prefix needed. 

I cant test now because the UAT server is offline, it will be back online 15 hours from now. I'll get back on the answer provided below. 

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try with this code

```
$data['invoiceNo'] = 'JGJEPOSONLINECS'.$order->id ;
```